Unable to play AACc codec with my realme bluetooth wireless, it has no sound
My bluetooth supports AAC codec. When I connect to my Ubuntu 24.04 it is connected, but no sound in sound settings. It shows the AAC codec, but there's no sound. I tried many troubleshooting attempts, but nothing worked. I tried common troubleshooting methods like install and re-install pipewire & bluetooth and aslo pipewire-pulse.conf file and bluetooth conf file but nothing worked.
This is my pactl info:
Server String: /run/user/1000/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 35
Server Protocol Version: 35
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 207
Tile Size: 65472
User Name: naveen
Host Name: Asus-VivoBook
Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 1.0.7)
Server Version: 15.0.0
Default Sample Specification: float32le 2ch 48000Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: bluez_output.98_47_44_50_36_65.1
Default Source: alsa_input.pci-0000_03_00.6.analog-stereo
Cookie: 9173:bb4b


Please edit the question and add all the steps you have tried and any errors or messages you got. This way no one wastes time telling you something you have already tried. As written then is nothing here that can be used to help you.

I tried Install and re-install pipewire and bluetooth and also tried to edit Bluetooth confiq file but nothing worked

Why tell me edit the question and add the info

ok sorry im new to this
